# Data structures for jinja

Tags: python, data-structures, jinja2

Brief: I am creating a website that displays events I have scraped off other websites.

Problem:
At the moment I can display the events by day but have to list everything out manually. No for loops.

This is because I have a dictionary of lists I believe. 
To get the title of a one of an event happening today the syntax is:

```
{{D.rows0[1].title}}
```

where D is a dictionary
`rows0` is a dynamic variable that represents the day, `rows1`, `rows2` exists as well. `rowsX` contains `title`, `date`, `x`, `y`, `z` etc information about events.

that would return something like "talk on x"

The reason I cannot iterate through the data structure because of the dynamic variable ( I was trying to do in `Jinja`). I am relatively new to data structures and hadn't realized that dynamic data structures would cause such problems.

I have messed around with a variety of different for loops and gave up. I then decided to change my data structure to a dictionary of arrays, a problem arose about passing the dictionary of arrays into the html page.

Conclusion. My question is should I find a way to iterate through the dynamic variable with `Jinja`? Find a way to pass an array into the `.html` file or am I doing everything wrong?

FURTHER EXPLANATION

functions I extract information from database

```
d = {}
D = {}

def extractor1(n):
    d["date" + str(n)] = (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=0)).date()
    D["rows" + str(n)] = db.execute ("SELECT * FROM events WHERE date LIKE :date ORDER BY date", date = str(d["date" + str(n)]) +'%')
    return d, D
```

This is the data structure I cannot iterate through with for loops in Jinja..

Second function attempt for arrays:

for this function i never got to trying to iterate through it in Jinja because of the errors I was getting. D and d were still dictionaries, I was a bit creative with what data structure date and rows could be, I tried an array and a dictionary. But after trying to fix and coming up with new problems I decided that this might not be the best way.

```
 def extractor2(n):
    d[date[n]] = (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=0)).date()
    D[rows[n]] = db.execute ("SELECT * FROM events WHERE date LIKE :date ORDER BY date", date = str(str(d[date[n]])) +'%')
    return d, D
```

Jinja code was just a myriad of different for loops of which none worked.

Comment: Post how the template is invoked (the Python code) would help us see whether you are doing things correctly or completely wrong. Also what do you mean by dynamic variable?

Comment: So why not use a `rows` variable that is a list, rather than use `rows0`, `rows1`, etc.? Don't produce loads of numbered variable names when you could use one container; `for row in D.rows:` is trivial, trying to do dynamic variable names in Jinja is a nightmare (and it is in Python as well).

Comment: And if `D` is a dictionary, you can loop over `D` in Jinja to get the keys, and you can use `D[keyname]` to get the value. You probably want to loop over the sorted keys, but that'd use *lexicographical* ordering (so `row10` comes before `row2`). You can loop over `D.values()` too, but dictionaries do not retain ordering and should not be used if order is important.

Comment: Added more information to question.  @metatoaster  dyamic variable I think at least how I used it is when you assign a variables in a for loop with 'list' +str(x).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am slightly confused sorry. So rows should be a list, I define rows a list: rows = [x,y,x,..]? doesn't that still cause a problem? Also earlier today I realized that dictionaries don't retain ordering I kind of need ordering since I want the website to display the dates in order.

Comment: @Tanc27: why would that be a problem? Jinja templates [can loop just fine](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#for).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are painting yourself in a corner by dynamically producing numbered keys. You have a sequence, not a series of distinct pieces of data; extracting those keys again later on is only going to be painful.

Instead of numbered dictionary keys, use a *list*. You can combine the date and query data together into one tuple per entry:

```
results = []
for n in range(number_of_entries):
    date = (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=0)).date()
    rows = db.execute ("SELECT * FROM events WHERE date LIKE :date ORDER BY date", date = str(date) + '%')
    results.append((date, rows))
```

then loop over the resulting list in your Jinja template:

```html
{% for date, rows in results %}
  <tbody><tr><th colspan="3" class="event-date-header">{{ date }}</th></tr>
  {% for row in rows %}
      <tr>
          <td class="event-foo"><a href="{{ row[0] }}">{{ row[1].title }}</a></td>
          <td class="event-bar"><{{ row[2] }}</td>
          <td class="event-baz"><{{ row[3] }}</td>
  {% endfor %}
  <tbody>      
{% endfor %}
```

Instead of a tuple, a dictionary per entry would also be fine, but then you can't so easily use tuple assignment as shown in the outer Jinja loop above.

Comment: doesn't append only take in one argument?

Comment: @Tanc27: yes, sorry, the tuple parentheses were missing there.